# which control is best for adding text and radio buttons in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display the question and options, and for every option the radio button should be add, and also question number in should be in number circle. suggest me how can to do this one

```
        public Form2(string paperid)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (paperid != "")
        {
            var papers = doc.Descendants("paper");
            foreach (var paper in papers)
            {
                if (paper.Attribute("id").Value == paperid)
                {
                    var questions = paper.Descendants("question");
                    foreach (var question in questions)
                    {
                        Label ques = new Label();
                        ques.Text = question.Attribute("ques").Value;
                        this.Controls.Add(ques);

                        var options = question.Descendants("option");
                        var i = 0;
                        foreach (var option in options)
                        {
                            RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton();
                            rdbtn.Name = "rdbtn" + i;
                            this.Controls.Add(rdbtn);
                            rdbtn.Text = option.Value;
                            i++;

                        }

                    }
                    break;
                }
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: Labels and radio buttons...

Comment: yes and beside the radio button I want to display the option text

Comment: this question is off-topic for stackoverflow

Comment: the question and option text I am taking from the xml

Comment: if it is possible with labels means I will store that text into labels..but which control i have to use

Comment: You could use the text property of the radio button

Comment: what about the text of question sir?

Comment: i want output like this....1. What is an array? radiobutton1 Array is an collection. radiobutton2 some text  radiobutton3 soxe text radiobutton4 some text

Comment: only first question is displaying,no options for 1st question and not displaying remaining question and answers

Comment: You may have overlapping controls. Try setting the `Top` of each control equal to the `Bottom` of the previous one, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In comments, you don't seem to know what a `Control` is. Everyone is telling you to use `Label` and `RadioButton` so just do it.

In the VS designer, select `Label` from the toolbox and drag it into the form. Change some of its properties, and BOOM! You've done it!

In the comments you said that you need to "store" the text in the `Label`. Well, that can be wrong in some contexts. You store text in strings, not labels. The latter *displays* the text.

You also mentioned how you get the text i.e. From XML. But that's irrelevant, you can just store the text you got from XML in a string, let's call it `text`. And then you change the `Text` property of the label.

```
label.Text = text;
```

Now your label will display the text.

**EDIT**

let me assume that you are not using VisualStudio. You can also do this with code. First you need to create a `Form`.

```
Form form = new Form();
form.Show();
//set properties of the form
Label label = new Label();
//set properties of the label. E.g. Text, width, position etc
form.Controls.Add(label);
```

So after you created the label, you set the text using the code before the edit and now your label should appear on the form.

Comment: for which control I have to add that label and radio button

Comment: Just add them to the `Form`! Are you using Visual Studio? @AnushaGajulapalli

Comment: Iam the beginner to windows form  so can you please tell me how to do

Comment: Edited @AnushaGajulapalli

Comment: Then just don't create the form, and change the word `form` to `this` @AnushaGajulapalli

Comment: i did that one also but it is not displaying the output and even i tried with flow layout panel also

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (id != "")
        {
            var papers = doc.Descendants("paper");
            foreach (var paper in papers)
            {
                if (paper.Attribute("id").Value == id)
                {
                    var questions = paper.Descendants("question");
                    var j = 1;
                    foreach (var question in questions)
                    {
                       GroupBox Ques&Ansoptn = new GroupBox();
                       Ques&Ansoptn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(720, 120);
                       Ques&Ansoptn.Text = question.Attribute("ques").Value;
                       Ques&Ansoptn.Location = new Point(15, 40*j);
                       Ques&Ansoptn.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
                        this.Controls.Add(Ques&Ansoptn);
                        var options = question.Descendants("option");
                        var i =1;
                        foreach (var option in options)
                        {
                            RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton();
                            rdbtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 20);
                            rdbtn.Location = new Point(20, 20 * i);
                            rdbtn.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
                            rdbtn.Text = option.Value;
                            Ques&Ansoptn.Controls.Add(rdbtn);
                            i++;
                        }
                        j = j+3;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }


        }
    }
```